# How to raise an error with decorator for unit testing?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

I would like to do something in my unit testing before it fails and using decorator to do so

Here is my code :

```
import requests
import unittest
import test


class ExceptionHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.f(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as err:
            print('do smth')
            raise err


class Testing(unittest.TestCase):
    @ExceptionHandler
    def test_connection_200(self):
        r = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
        self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 400)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

But it throws me an :

```
TypeError: test_connection_200() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

How can I do something when my test fail, then having the normal failing behavior of unitest?

Edit :
I would like to do something before my test fail like write a  log and then continue the normal process of failing.

If possible with a decorator.

Edit bis the solution thanks to @Thymen :

```
import requests
import unittest
import test


class ExceptionHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.f(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as err:
            print('do smth')
            raise err


class Testing(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_connection_200(self):
        @ExceptionHandler
        def test_connection_bis(self):
            r = requests.get("https://www.google.com")
            print(r.status_code)
            self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 400)
        test_connection_bis(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Comment: You can create a function inside the test method. This makes it independent of the call to the test method. In any case use `def test_connection_200(self); @ExceptionHandler; def test_exception(); your test....`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment may not have been clear, so hereby the solution in code

```
class Testing(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_connection_200(self):

        @ExceptionHandler
        def test_connection():
            r = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
            self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 400)

        with self.assertRaises(AssertionError):
            test_connection()
```

The reason that this works is that there is no dependency on the call for the test (`test_connection_200`) , and the actual functionality that you are trying to test (the `ExceptionHandler`).

#### Edit

The line

```
with self.assertRaises(AssertionError):
    test_connection()
```

Checks if `test_connection()` raises an `AssertionError`. If it does not raises this error, it will fail the test.

If you want the test to fail (because of the `AssertionError`), you can remove the `with` statement, and only call `test_connection()`. This will make the test fail directly.

Comment: i would like my test to faiil, i would like to do something before my test fail. @Thymen Withd your solution the test does not fail :/

Comment: The test does fail, in the sense that it is catching an `AssertionError`. That is what `self.assertRaises` checks. If you want it to provide an error message instead, you can remove the line `with self.assertRaises(AssertionError)`, and only call `test_connection()`. That will result in an `AssertionError`.